# SQLite Drop Table Causes Database is Locked Error

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, ipad

I have created a little database upgrade tool to update our sqlite database tables based on PRAGMA user_version. It has been working well until recently I needed to drop a table entirely.

obviously the drop table command is

```
DROP TABLE tbl;
```

The sql instructions are executed using:

```
NSString *currentUpdateStatement = [upgradeStatements objectAtIndex:statementNumber];
DLog(@"Update statement is: %@", currentUpdateStatement);
const char *sql_stmt = [currentUpdateStatement UTF8String];
char *errMsg;
//Start executing the upgrade command
if (sqlite3_exec(self.database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    DLog(@"Upgrade statement %i successful", statementNumber);
} else {
    NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:errMsg];
    ELog(@"Upgrading failed at statement %i in version %i. Message: %@",
    statementNumber, newVersionNumber, errorMessage);
    [NSException raise:@"Database upgrade failed"
    format:@"Database could not be upgraded to version %i. "
    "Failed at command %i due to error '%@'",newVersionNumber, statementNumber, errorMessage];
 }
```

Every time I try to run a drop table command, the execution fails with 'database is locked' with a result SQLITE_LOCKED.

All other commands are completely fine. I tried to read the SQL documentation over and over with no luck.
What do you guys think?

Comment: Some other database connection has an active transaction.

Comment: @CL the database is only being used by 1 instance in the application, and it is only returned after the database upgrade has finished, so there cannot be another active transaction.

Comment: It does not matter what you assume; the database thinks that there is another transaction.

Comment: @hishamaus did you find a solution for this. I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

A missing sqlite3_finalize(statement) after the antecedent transaction can cause this error.

Comment: according to SQLite3 docs, sqlite3_exec is a wrapper statement that executes sqlite3_prepare_v2(), sqlite3_step(), and sqlite3_finalize(), I am assuming I wouldn't need to call finalize.

Comment: @hishamaus Are you using `sqlite3_exec` for everything?

Comment: @CL actually just started using it with the above code. I tried both the normal prepare step finalize and this, both didn't work. One thing to note, the drop commands will work fine if the table was not touched (if records were previously inserted and deleted consider it touched)